# Retrieve EC2 instance attributes and flatten the output using AWS EC2 CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am using the command below aws ec2 describe-instances to return list of running EC2s. The output is a TSV in 2 lines, first line being Account ID (OwnerId), and the rest of the query is displayed at the second line. I would like to make all the attributes to be flattened in one line, but due to the nature of the json output of the API calls, is there a way to manipulate the output to be in just one line?

`aws ec2 describe-instances --output text  --profile $account --query 'Reservations[*].[[OwnerId, Instances[*].[InstanceId, InstanceType, State.Name, Platform, Placement.AvailabilityZone, PublicIpAddress, PrivateIpAddress,[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value][0][0],[Tags[?Key==`Environment`].Value][0][0]]]]'  --filter --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running  >> $outfile`

`1234567890
i-03cxxxxxxxdab t2.medium   running windows ap-southeast-1a 10.0.0.0    10.10.0.10  api-abc-prod-01 PROD`

desired output in one line

`1234567890  i-03cxxxxxxxdab    t2.medium   running windows ap-southeast-1a 10.0.0.0    10.10.0.10  api-abc-prod-01 PROD`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, AWS cli offer to specify the output formate, so you can set the output to `text` then replace the new line with space. you can try

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text  --profile test --query 'Reservations[*].[[OwnerId, Instances[*].[InstanceId, InstanceType, State.Name, Platform, Placement.AvailabilityZone, PublicIpAddress, PrivateIpAddress,[Tags[?Key==Name].Value][0][0],[Tags[?Key==Environment].Value][0][0]]]]'  --filter --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --output text | tr '\r\n' ' '
```

**Text Output Format**

> The text format organizes the AWS CLI's output into tab-delimited
>   lines. It works well with traditional Unix text tools such as grep,
>   sed, and awk, as well as the text processing performed by PowerShell.
>
> The text output format follows the basic structure shown below. The
>   columns are sorted alphabetically by the corresponding key names of
>   the underlying JSON object.

```
IDENTIFIER  sorted-column1 sorted-column2
IDENTIFIER2 sorted-column1 sorted-column2
```

so you are good to go with pipe using `tr '\r\n' ' '`

Or you can use `awk`

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text  --profile test --query 'Reservations[*].[[OwnerId, Instances[*].[InstanceId, InstanceType, State.Name, Platform, Placement.AvailabilityZone, PublicIpAddress, PrivateIpAddress,[Tags[?Key==Name].Value][0][0],[Tags[?Key==Environment].Value][0][0]]]]'  --filter --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running  | awk 1 ORS=' '
```

**update:**

If you want to append ownerID with each instance details then use this.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text   --query 'Reservations[*].[[OwnerId, Instances[*].[InstanceId, InstanceType, State.Name, Platform, Placement.AvailabilityZone, PublicIpAddress, PrivateIpAddress,[Tags[?Key==Name].Value][0][0],[Tags[?Key==Environment].Value][0][0]]]]'  --filter --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running | paste -d" " - -
```

Comment: I have tried both `tr '\r\n' ' '` and `awk 1 ORS=' '` it returned the output in a long single line

Comment: You mentioned that you need in one line?

Comment: what i meant was, each instance displayed in one line, eg. instance 1 ownerid publicipaddress privateipaddress name \nInstance 2 ownerid publicipaddress privateipaddress

Comment: that works greatly, thank you! I corrected it slightly `aws ec2 describe-instances --output text   --query 'Reservations[*].[[OwnerId, Instances[*].[InstanceId, InstanceType, State.Name, Platform, Placement.AvailabilityZone, PublicIpAddress, PrivateIpAddress,[Tags[?Key==Name].Value][0][0],[Tags[?Key==Environment].Value][0][0]]]]'  --filter --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running | paste -d"\t" - -`

Answer (score 1):

As recommended in the top answer in [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools) --> you can use jq to do this https://stedolan.github.io/jq/, check the tutorial here on extracting the relevent fields... https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/